# For $G$ a group and $H\unlhd G$, with $G$ and $G/A$ simple, there does not exist a chain of subgroups....

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here is my question..

[image]

I've started with my knowledge of normal subgroups:

C$\cap$A  is normal in A, and A is simple, and thus C$\cap$A = A or {e}, but I', not sure where to head..

Comment: Assume $C\cap A=A$. Then $C/A\lhd G/A$, hence $C/A=1$ and $C=A$. But then $B\lhd A$ contradicts the fact that $A$ is simple.

Comment: Assume $C\cap A=\{e\}$. Then the image of $C$ under the quotient $q:G\to G/A$ is  $q(C)\cong C/C\cap A=C $ which is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G/A$ and hence must be $G/A$. But then $G/A$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup which is a contradiction.